# MS Access Query issue with IIF

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office

I'm trying to setup a query that checks a retails column and verify it against a post paid column. The idea is that any retail over 249.90 should have a Y in the post paid and anything under 249.89 should have an N. Anything that's not correct I want it to show the issue and anything correct it doesn't need to show. I'm using an IIF statement in the query but I'm not even sure this is the best way to go about it. Currently the query is just pulling up everything. No errors.

Any info or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```
Issues: IIf([Retail]>249.9,IIf([Post Paid]="N",IIf([Retail]<249.89,IIf([Post Paid]="Y","Issue",0))))
```

Thanks for your help!
-D

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
select t.*
from t
where (retail > 249.9 and [Post Paid] <> "N") or
      (retail < 249.9 and [Post Paid] = "N")
```

Comment: Not sure that's doing what I want. Admittedly I'm not great with SQL. I tried to input what you gave me and here it is in SQL maybe I entered it wrong?            
 `SELECT DT.Field1 AS Pack, DT.Field2 AS [Desc], DT.Field9 AS Prefix, DT.Field10 AS Retail, DT.Field74 AS Merch, DT.Field70 AS [Post Paid], IIf([Retail]>249.9 And [Post Paid]<>"N" Or [Retail]<249.89 And [Post Paid]="N",True,False) AS Issues
FROM DT
WHERE (((DT.Field74) Like "EA"))
ORDER BY DT.Field10; `

Comment: what that did was add -1 and 0's were the 0's are the issues and -1's are okay. but its also still showing everything

Comment: This would be easier if it would allow me to just filter the the "Issues" Column but it doesn't seem to want to let me use `Like "Issue"` as a criteria.

Comment: Gordon gave you a WHERE clause and you didn't use it, that's what you did wrong.